# uitableviewcell disclosureindicator accessoryview alignment

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, accessoryview

Is it possible to change accessory view position/alignment on UITableViewCell (By default it center align) ?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot by using any apple provided API but you can create your own view and place it at the right side of the cell.

You just need to set the frame of that uiview object while creating that object or by `frame` property, like this

```
UIView *viewObject = {[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 10, 25, 25)];
```

or

```
viewObject.frame = CGRectMake(280, 10, 25, 25)
```